# The number of subspaces in a $d$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{F}_q$

Tags: combinatorics

I'm trying to find an expression to asymptotically estimate the total number of subspaces (summing together all dimensions) $\mathbb{F}_q^d$. I know that you can count the number of subspaces of a fixed dimension with gaussian binomial coefficients. But then I would need to approximate the sum of these binomials and I don't know that. I was thinking that I could do it using some q-analog of the binomial theorem (like evaluating the sum of binomials by expanding (1+x)^n and setting x = 1), but the formulas I found I either couldn't understand or wouldn't help me evaluating this sum.

I'm also interested in counting chains of subspaces. That is, given a $d$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{F}_q$, how many  chains of $k$ subspaces $0 < L_1 < L_2 \cdots < L_{k} < \mathbb{F}_q^d$ exist? I think I saw a theorem suggesting this should be something like $q^{O(d^2)}$, but I have no idea how they arrived at this number, and it doesn't help me enough since I would need to know what the constant in the $O(d^2)$ is. Does anyone have any advice for how I could approach these problems?

Comment: Chains (also known as flags) are similar to subspaces; they are counted by expressions involving q-factorials. The easiest case is complete flags (when $k = d - 1$); the number of these is $(d)!_q$. What is the relevant asymptotic regime here? Is $d \to \infty$ while $q$ is fixed?

Comment: Yes, I'm thinking of $d\rightarrow \infty$ with fixed $q$. I had figured out the case for $k = d-1$, but unfortunately that's what I need. I really need to know what happens when it's something like $k = d/2$ which seems to make this much more complicated.